# Excluding positive samples in Negative Sampling

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I was reading several **[Skipgram Negative Sampling codes such as this one in Github](https://github.com/theeluwin/pytorch-sgns/blob/master/model.py)** and became curious how to exclude positive samples among sampled negative ones as the code seems not properly doing it. As I understood, the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4546)  says that the negative sampling is sampling a few unrelated words and minimizing their likelihood. Don't we have to strictly exclude positive samples being picked from negative sampling? I guess we have to further check whether samples from negative sampling includes one from positive samples.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In theorie you are correct. But:

1. it is computationally expensive to check if a negative word does not appear in the actual context. You have to go through your whole corpus to check (or have a data structure which facilitates such checks). The whole point of the skipgram model is to speed up training.
2. It won't actually be a problem because it does not happen that often and when it happens once or twice it won't do much harm.

So it is more a problem of wording. Negative samples are not actually negative but random.